# java 7 update25 applet not working on IE10

Tags: applet, java

Anyone has success of running applet page below with IE10 installing the jre7u25?

http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

Are there any way to disable update of java when using runapplet below?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Comment: The most updated java version fixes security issues. You should consider that.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone has success of running applet page below with IE installing the jre7u25?

I don't use Windows, but I'm sure someone has.  At least for *some* version of IE.  It is (frankly) implausible that it doesn't work in the vast majority of cases.

Please be specific about what version of Windows and IE you are talking about, and how it is "not working" for you.

> Are there any way to disable update of java when using runapplet(jnlp) below?

This doesn't make sense.  JNLP doesn't update Java.

---

The problem with Java and IE10 seems to be to do with 32bit versus 64bit.  Apparently IE10 defaults to running in 32bit mode, even on a 64bit platform.  And a 32bit browser requires a 32bit Java plugin.

- Check what versions of Java you have actually got installed.
- Try switching IE10 to "Enhanced Protection Mode" and see if it can find 64bit Java.
- Try manually installing a 32bit Java.

Reference:

- http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml

Comment: IE version is 10 and from what I've seen deployjava.js is unable to get the installed JREs nor launch the JREs. It keeps saying the java is not installed. I've seen plenty of people having same problem.

Comment: The message is as follows in the test applet page. No working Java was detected on your system.
Install Java by clicking the button below.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why the problem occurs.

IE10 runs in 64bit frame but the tab runs in 32bit mode.

There is a way to run tab in 64 bit mode in windows8.

http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2012/08/25/how-to-make-internet-explorer-10-run-in-64-bit/

But it doesn't work in windows7.

I tried with chrome ie tab which runs chrome and ie in 32bit mode in which the applet works.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems too with my applet. In Google Chrome from the start works perfectly.
Internet explorer 10 seems not recognize new Java 7 u 25 installed on PC after automatic upgrade.
I solved problem with next steps:

1. uninstall all Java 7 versions on PC
2. Download Java package on http://www.oldapps.com/java.php (depending what you need 32 or 64 bit)
3. install Java

   After that IE10 recognized Java and applet works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just add the env var like the next post says. That functions for me!!!

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2530883?tstart=0

And add too the parameter at execution time like the next post

http://nicolask.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/oracle-jnitiator-version-too-low-please-install-version-1-1-8-2-or-higher/

I hope this help you!!! And as an advice use chrome for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get the latest java (7 update 25, 32 bit) to run ALL THE TIME in Internet Explorer 10 desktop mode (in Windows 8 64 bit) was to create a new shortcut to:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Then hitting advanced (in the shortcut) and choosing RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR

If you do not want to do that (for security reasons), the work around that I found, was to install Chrome (as Java works all the time) and use that for sites that require Java.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

the 64-bit java plugin is not compatible with Enhanced Protected Mode, which is a new type of sandbox they have for IE10 and IE11.

Therefore , disable Enhanced Protected Mode, install 32-bit JRE and now IE should run 32-bit child processes for each window, which will be compatible with Your 32-bit Java plugin.

This is valid for the desktop-mode IE in Win8. The new-flat-unintuitive-mode IE has Enhanced Protected Mode enable per default. You can check by using Process Explorer, and showing the Integrity column. If "AppContainer" is displayed, then EPM is used

Hope this helps